# Python: Why does heap give incorrect first pop?

Tags: python, heap

I'm trying to create a max heap by negating all the values of a list, but it doesn't seem to be working:

```
import heapq
x = range(1,10)
neg = [-n for n in x]
heapq.heappop(neg) # -1
heapq.heappop(neg) # -9
heapq.heappop(neg) # -8
```

Yet if I do

```
heapq.heappop(x) # 1
heapq.heappop(x) # 2
heapq.heappop(x) # 3
```

It seems to work correctly. Any idea as to why -1 is returning?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should not use `heappush/heappop` unless you have the heap invariant maintained in the first place.

To create a heap from an existing list, use `heapq.heapify(mylist)`.

```
>>> neg = [-n for n in range(1,10)]
>>> neg[0]  # peek
-1
>>> heapq.heapify(neg)
>>> neg[0]  # peek
-9
>>> -heapq.heappop(neg)  # largest element
9
```

Comment: Yeah but if I do `x = heapq.heapify(mylist)`, then try to do `heapq.heappop(x)`, I get `TypeError: heap argument must be a list`

Comment: because `heapify` operates in-place and returns `None`.

Comment: @AlanH `heapify` returns `None`

Comment: @AlanH, the `heapify` is basically changing your list `neg`, but doesn't return the changed list so you can't assign it to another variable. If you don't want that, make a copy of your list like `neg_new=neg.copy()` and do a `heapify` on the new list.

Answer (score 0):

`heapq.heappop` is *only* for minheaps; you can't just make a maxheap and expect minheap based functions to work on it, because it doesn't observe the minheap invariant.

If the goal is to pop off -9 first, you need to make your heap support the proper invariants, by (efficiently, `O(n)`) heapifying it first:

```
heapq.heapify(neg)
```

after which your code will pop from -9 down to -1.

If you're trying for a maxheap, that's not supported. [All the publically documented `heapq` functions work with minheaps](https://docs.python.org/3/library/heapq.html) (emphasis added):

> The API below differs from textbook heap algorithms in two aspects: (a) We use zero-based indexing. This makes the relationship between the index for a node and the indexes for its children slightly less obvious, but is more suitable since Python uses zero-based indexing. (b) **Our pop method returns the smallest item, not the largest (called a “min heap” in textbooks; a “max heap” is more common in texts because of its suitability for in-place sorting).**

There are a few selected (and undocumented) maxheap based functions in the module that will work, e.g. `heapq._heappop_max`, but they're not a documented part of the API, and could change or disappear at any time.

Comment: minheap is just maxheap from the other end, negating the elements is a perfectly valid way to do it.  Perhaps even the canonical way.

Comment: @wim: Yeah, I reread and realized the negation may have been intended to simulate a maxheap using minheaps, so I updated to cover both possibilities.